# How do you keep a Service in the foreground when an Activity is killed by the system, but stop the Service if the user swipes it away?

Tags: android, service

Is there a way to tell if the user stopped the app vs the system?

For example, when you use a music player on Android, you can stop the Service by swiping the app away. You can also pause the music and swipe the notification away. The system can kill the app and the music still plays. How is that achieved?

Currently my Service never stops. I need to use developers settings to stop my service which is not user friendly.

I think in my example that when the user stops the music via notification, that the Service is shut down so the notification can be swiped away. Then restarted if the user hits play.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override onTaskRemoved()

```
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        // clean up and shut down
    }
```